# once I've been able to... I can now enjoy

Tags: tense, phrase-usage, infinitives

Can would + infinitive be followed by simple present? For example:

> Once I've been able to get rid of this xxx, I feel more like myself as in now.

Because I've just read “Once you had put the pieces back together, you were never quite the same as you'd been before the fall.” Whereas in this case, it is Past Perfect Simple followed by simple past.

Comment: First, remove the contraction in your example. I don't see where the *would + infinitive* you mention is. Also your "I've just read" example is just wrong. Where did you read it? The usual format I think you are looking for is "Once... I will... "Once" does not settle anything, so the response cannot be simple past, which indicates a finalized action.

Answer (score 1):

"I've" is not the contraction for "I would" (or "I would have").  "I'd have" or "I would've" are both correct contractions.  "I've" is a contraction for "I have", and so your example sentence says:

> Once I have been able to get over this [something], I feel more like myself (as in now).

With a future condition, either the future simple or the future hypothetical are OK:

> Once I am able to get over this cold, I will feel more like myself.
>
> If I am able to get over this cold, I would feel more like myself.

So I'm not quite sure I understand your question.  But if you are asking whether "would+infinitve" in one part of a sentence can be paired with the simple present in another, then yes:

> I would give you a hundred dollars if you eat that bug.

The example you give from the book is set in the past, but you can say something similar in the present tense:

> Once you put the pieces back together, you are never quite the same as you'd been before the fall.

or future:

> Once you put the pieces back together, you will never be quite the same as you'd been before the fall.

If you want to refine your question I can give you a better answer.